# Discord Temporary mute Went Wrong

Tags: python, bots, discord.py

I was making a temporary Mute command for my discord but I don't know what command should i use, No errors where given.Its an unexpected result,Also if u can tell me how to add a reason it would be great!.The command is below.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True, name="tempmute")
@has_permissions(mute_members=True)
async def tempmute(ctx, *, target: Member):
    if target.server_permissions.administrator:
        await bot.say("Target is an admin")
    else:
        try:
            await bot.mute(target)
            await bot.say('{} got muted by {}'.format(target.mention, message.author))
        except Exception:
            await bot.say("Something went wrong")

@tempmute.error
async def tempmute_error(error, ctx):
    if isinstance(error, CheckFailure):
        await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "You do not have permissions")
    elif isinstance(error, BadArgument):
        await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "Could not identify target")
    else:
        raise error
```

but the command neither mutes or temporary mutes the target nor sends any error, it just says "something went wrong". Also i can't find a command in which i can get the member who called the command in line wait bot.say('{} got muted by {}'.format(target.mention, message.author)) **message.author** What should i write instead of that to get the member who called the command to mute the target

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't mute a user just by typing `bot.mute(user)` , you have to add him a mute role and then configure that role in your server to not be able to talk in any channel. Also I don't get again like in the `kick` command why you add `*`, this is used if you expect more arguments in a command which you don't in this case. One way to approach this is like that:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True, name="tempmute")
@has_permissions(mute_members=True)
async def tempmute(ctx, target: Member):
    if target.server_permissions.administrator:
        await bot.say("Target is an admin")
    else:
        role = discord.utils.get(target.server.roles, name='Muted')#this line searched in the server if the role "Muted" exists
        await bot.add_roles(target, role) # this line adds to the user the muted role
        await bot.say("User {}, has been muted by moderator {}.".format(target.mention, ctx.message.auhtor.mention)) # this line sends an messsage

@tempmute.error
async def tempmute_error(error, ctx):
    if isinstance(error, CheckFailure):
         await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "You do not have permissions")
    elif isinstance(error, BadArgument):
        await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "Could not identify target")
    else:
        raise error
```

Comment: Thankyou sir, But can you please tell me how to mute a member only for a certian amoun fo time and reason